# Eloquent innodb - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found Table doesn't exist

Tags: eloquent

I have this weird crash and trying for few hours to solve with no success, check everywhere on the internet and didn't find a solution.

I am running Eloquent (without laravel). I have two servers (frontend and backend). The DB is in the backend server.

I am running the **exact same code** to connect to the database using laravel from both servers. From the backend server everything works. In the frontend server, I get mixed result. Out of 9 tables:

1. three works, and I am able to retrieve the data.
2. three return [items:protected] => Array (), while table has data to return.
3. three cause fatal error SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found Table doesn't exist

from #1 I understand that this is not related to issue with database user/password.

for #2, I checked the queries using getQueryLog(), and I run the queries in phpmyadmin, and they work.

from what I observed so far, all the tables that cause #3 are all InnoDB. Why my other tables are MyIsam I don't know.

And the exact same code works in the backend server, so it is not an issue with tables names are in singular or some other code related issue.

backend server is php 5.5.9, eloquent 5.4.45

frontend server is php 5.6.32, eloquent 5.4.36

Any idea what to do about #2 (return data empty) and #3 (php fatal error)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found this crazy bug(s).
First, I found out that we had an old version of the database on the frontend server. It was not supposed to be there, so I didn't even think about it as a possibility.

In addition, there was a problem in the code:

```
$dbhost = __MYSQLDB_HOST__;
$dbuser = 'xxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxx';
$dbname = 'xxxxx';

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection(array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',  // <= this is the problem!!!
    'database'  => $dbname,
    'username'  => $dbuser,
    'password'  => $dbpass,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => ''
));
```

As you can see, when connecting to the database it used localhost instead of the $dbhost variable which contained the remote database host on the backend server.